# What does "cc" mean in airport command results?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac

I'm using the `airport` command to scan nearby wifi networks ( `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport -s` ), and I've decoded the other datapoints. What does `cc` mean in this context?

Example output:

```
          SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
 Stevens-Guest 18:64:72:37:fa:21 -76  11      Y  -- NONE
 Stevens-Media 18:64:72:37:73:42 -67  11      Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cc    // Country code reported - can be null

https://github.com/unwitting/airport-scan (no clue if this is the official, or a redux, but the rest of the fields matched up)

Comment: Of course! Makes sense, though I'm wondering what contexts it's used?

Comment: Good Q, seems to have some impact on which networks a machine will connect to, but not sure of much beyond that.  Some related info - http://www.howtogeek.com/211993/how-to-fix-conflicting-country-codes-and-improve-your-macs-wi-fi/

Comment: Right, probably transmission power regulations, etc. Thanks!